# Crash when resume an AdMob RewardedVideoAd

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

With the last AdMob version, `15.0.0`, I getting a crash when try to resume a `RewardedVideoAd`after return from another Activity.

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.m
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.y.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529004@12.5.29 (000308-192802242):262)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.c.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529004@12.5.29 (000308-192802242):54)
     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529004@12.5.29 (000308-192802242):57)
     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzev.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaez.zzc(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafk.resume(Unknown Source)
     at com.byteghoul.grimdefender.GhoulAdsAndroid3.onResume(GhoulAdsAndroid3.java:411)
     at com.byteghoul.grimdefender.AndroidLauncher.onResume(AndroidLauncher.java:437)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1198)
     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5530)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3047)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The integration seems ok, I just follow the AdMob docs doing nothing strange.

I checked the Google AdMob github sample and I got the same error.

For futher information, here are my RewardedVideo wrapper:

```
class VideoAd @Inject constructor(@Named(BaseActivity.BaseModule.ACTIVITY_CONTEXT) private val context: Context) {

private var isAlreadyPrepared: Boolean = false
private lateinit var rewardedVideoAd: RewardedVideoAd
private val customListener: CustomVideoListener = CustomVideoListener()
private var adsListener: AdsListener = object : AdsListener {}
val isVideoLoaded: Boolean
    get() = rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded

fun prepare(listener: AdsListener) {
    adsListener = listener
    if (isAlreadyPrepared) {
        return
    }
    rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(context)
    rewardedVideoAd.rewardedVideoAdListener = customListener
    val adRequest: AdRequest = AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(ADS_ID_TEST_DEVICE)
        .addTestDevice(ADS_ID_TEST_DEVICE_2)
        .build()
    rewardedVideoAd.loadAd(VIDEO_ADS_ID, adRequest)
    isAlreadyPrepared = true
}

fun show() {
    if (isVideoLoaded) {
        rewardedVideoAd.show()
    } else {
        logNonFatalException("Video Ad not loaded successfully before show it")
        adsListener.onVideoAdNotLoaded()
    }
}

fun onPauseActivity() {
    rewardedVideoAd.pause(context)
}

fun onResumeActivity() {
    rewardedVideoAd.resume(context)
}

fun onDestroyActivity() {
    rewardedVideoAd.destroy(context)
}

private inner class CustomVideoListener : RewardedVideoAdListener {
    override fun onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        adsListener.onAdsFinishedSuccessfully()
    }

    override fun onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    }

    override fun onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    }

    override fun onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    }

    override fun onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    }

    override fun onRewarded(reward: RewardItem?) {
        adsListener.onAdsFinishedSuccessfully()
    }

    override fun onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    }

    override fun onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching in google bug tracking seems that this is a bug of the 15.0.0 version:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/XtVZFQ-nl98

Possible solutions are:

- Downgrade version to a previous stable one.
- Wait until google launch a fix.

Comment: What version i should downgrade to? Also where do i see all available versions of a package?

Comment: I am using following dependencies but still getting error: com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1,
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1,
Also tried 15.0.0 and 12.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I changed the AdMob version 15.0.0 to 15.0.1 and it works well .

Comment: No, It is not a proper solution i also use the 15.0.1 version of admob but it still show me same error