# How to solve this error 'com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.m '?

Tags: android, admob, mopub, mobile-ad-mediation, admob-rewardedvideoad

am using firebase adapter in my project, now am integrate admob for rewarded ad it's working fine, but every video after completion it will throw following error...

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.m
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.mediation.client.y.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):262)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.c.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):54)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.reward.client.e.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12685008@12.6.85 (020306-197041431):56)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzej.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzahb.zze(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzahm.resume(Unknown Source)
    at com.mopub.mobileads.GooglePlayServicesRewardedVideo$1.onResume(GooglePlayServicesRewardedVideo.java:84)
    at com.mopub.common.MoPubLifecycleManager.onResume(MoPubLifecycleManager.java:83)
    at com.mopub.common.MoPub.onResume(MoPub.java:257)
    at com.coderays.realquiz.RealQuizDashBoard.onResume(RealQuizDashBoard.java:956)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1280)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6096)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3011)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1361)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

i will try this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/49959522/6477998 but still throw this error.

my gradle is..

```
dependencies {
     implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-interstitial:5.0.0@aar') {
     transitive = true
      }
    // For rewarded videos. This will automatically also include interstitials
     implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-rewardedvideo:5.0.0@aar') {
     transitive = true
      }
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
  }
```

Which one to change, please give me a solution, am searching still 3 days but no improvement.

Advance thanx...

Comment: Try this `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`

Comment: sorry @ Nilesh Rathod still error will throw..

Comment: please anyone give me a solution for this error

Comment: test case try to down grade `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1`

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.1` is not working, so am using `15.0.2` it show another error like `org.gradle.api.GradleException: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other `

Comment: my dependencies from build project `classpath  com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1` latest version

Comment: Please any one give me a solution for this error, its still not clear.

Comment: error fixed. If you want to known see my answer. thanx

Comment: Where is your answer

Comment: sorry now only am updating please check it now! [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51277987/6477998]

Answer (score 0):

thanks, the error will be fixed after long time.

**Step 1:** i remove my adapter class `GooglePlayServicesRewardedVideo.java` from `com.mopub.mobileads`( if you are using `GooglePlayServicesInterstitial.java` please remove ).

**Step 2:** then, put admob mediation sdk into build.gradle i.e `implementation 'com.mopub.mediation:admob:15.0.0.8'`.

**Step 3:** then, remove the following lines in your rewarded display activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   MoPubRewardedVideos.initializeRewardedVideo(this);
   MoPub.onCreate(this); // remove 
   // ...
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MoPub.onPause(this); // remove 
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MoPub.onResume(this);  // remove 
}

// The following methods are required for Chartboost rewarded video mediation
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    MoPub.onStart(this); // remove 
}

@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    MoPub.onRestart(this); // remove 
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    MoPub.onStop(this); // remove 
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MoPub.onDestroy(this); // remove 
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    MoPub.onBackPressed(this); // remove 
  }
}
```

**Step 4 :** syn your project, and take a build. Its working fine without error.

thanks.